# onclick automaticly executing for all my elements, but not in element where it clicked

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<section class="get">
<li><button onclick="ShowMyTables()" id="show_my_tables"> Show my tables</button></li>
<ul id = orders> 
</ul>
</section>  `
```

JS:

in theory, when i click "show_my_tables", i'll see list of links with names of my table.And when i click on one of this links, i would see the name of this table,but when i clicking "show_my_tables" all my onclick executing

```
          function ShowMyTables(){
    $(orders).empty();      
     $.ajax({ 
     type:"GET", 
     url:"/table/show_my_tables", 
     success:function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.nameArr.length; i++) {

  $(orders).append("<li>Table name:<a  onclick = '"+ShowThisTable(data.nameArr[i])+"'> " + data.nameArr[i] + "</a></li>");

      }
     }

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `onclick` functions are firing because you are invoking `ShowThisTable()` during each iteration of your `for` loop.

`"ShowThisTable("` and `")"` need to be printed inside the string literals you are concatenating:

```
function ShowMyTables(){

    $('#orders').empty();      
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"GET", 
        url:"/table/show_my_tables", 
        success:function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.nameArr.length; i++) {
            $(orders)
               .append("<li>Table name:<a  onclick = 'ShowThisTable(" + data.nameArr[i] + ")'> " + data.nameArr[i] + "</a></li>");

        }
    }
})
```

And the `id` for your `<ul>` elements needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
<section class="get">
    <li><button onclick="ShowMyTables()" id="show_my_tables"> Show my tables</button></li>
    <ul id ="orders"> 
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be outside of the list, because otherwise it will be destroyed when calling `empty()`, so `<li>` tags around your `<button>` aren't needed.

Id value for your unordered list should be enclosed in quotes, like this: `<ul id="orders">`. When accesing orders list through $ function, your argument should also be enclosed in quotes, since it's a string `"orders"` not a variable named `orders`.

Furthermore, if you're selecting an element by id you should prepend it's id with #, so to get an element of id "orders" you should use `$("#orders")`.

Also, i've noticed you want to assign an onclick listener to dynamically created list elements, but your approach is wrong. The way you're doing it now you execute function `ShowThisTable` and then add it's return value to  the string with your HTML.

Given a lot of basic mistakes in your code i'd suggest you revise HTML and javascript syntax before you move to more advanced topics, such as AJAX.

Comment: Thanx for u answer.How to assign  dynamically  onclick?

Comment: Instead of writing HTML inside of string like `<li>Table name etc..` you could create a DOM object using [syntax specified here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2). Using the $ function like that will return a variable with your `<li>` element. on which you can later assign onclick using jQuery `.on("click", function(){})`. Later, append it to body using `.appendTo("body")` on it

Comment: Also, check out chester's answer for a way to do it in a html string